# Custom fields for Powermail in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, powermail

I am working with powermail forms, where I need a custom multiselect powermail field.
Any idea how to configure the field?

I have added `tx_powermail.flexForm.type.addFieldOptions.new = New Field` in TCEFORM file, and I got new field in powermail form but how can i configure multiselect in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see the documentation part on https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddNewFields.md?
There is also a part that describes the datatype that can be set via TSConfig.

Comment: Yes I see that i want to know that how i configure the flexform for that field.
can i overwrite the powermail flexform.xml file?

Comment: To extend the FlexForm is described also in the documentation here: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForDevelopers/AddNewFlexFormProperties.md
If you want to completely overwrite the complete FlexForm of an extension, see https://www.in2code.de/en/recent/php-replace-flexform-of-an-extension/

Comment: This is not really an answer by Stack Overflow policies. Answers should not contain ONLY links to documentation but be self-contained, see "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer